# If you flip a fair coin $8$ times, what is the probability of getting exactly $3$ out of $8$ heads?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, contest-math

I am confused on how this works. Normally, probability is:

$$P = \frac{\text{Number of successes}}{\text{Number of total trials}}$$

For a problem like:

> If you flip a fair coin $8$ times, what is the probability of getting exactly $3$ out of $8$ heads?

The solution first depicts how many ways there are to choose $3$ heads. With:

$$\binom{8}{3}$$

Then what will the denominator be? Moreover what is this method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you flip the coin $8$ times you will have an 8-letter word in front of you consisting of "H"'s (for Heads) and "T"'s (for Tails). Now ask yourself:

1. How many such words are there? You are only interested only in the number of "H"'s in the words and not in their exact place, so there are $$\dbinom{8}{0}+\dbinom{8}{1}+\ldots+\dbinom{8}{8}=\sum_{k=0}^{8}\dbinom{8}{k}=(1+1)^8=2^8$$ where the last equation is due to the binomial identity (or theorem). This number gives you the denominator (number of different possible outcomes).
2. How many of these words have exactly $3$ "H"'s? You already have that this is equal to $\dbinom{8}{3}$.

Thus the required probability is equal - as you correctly know - to $$\frac{\text{Number of successes}}{\text{Number of total trials}}=\frac{\dbinom{8}{3}}{2^8}$$

---

Note however that this works because each possible result has the same probability. So I will not agree with your first sentence that "normally...".

Now, combinatorics are used in order to count things in a more efficient way. In the hypothetical case that you have a lot (really lot) of spare time and a lot of fingers (>>20) you could count things using time and fingers and combinatorics would be useless. If that is not the case then you will have to use combinatorics in probability rather frequently.

Answer (score 4):

Numerator: how many ways can you get exactly 3 heads and 5 tails? This is a matter of choosing which three of the eight trials get heads: $\binom{8}{3}$.

Denominator: how many possible outcomes are there? For each trial there are two outcomes, so there are $2^8$ possible outcomes for eight flips.

---

Addendum: As noted in the other answer, the only reason we are allowed to use combinatorics in this manner for this question is because every possible outcome of 8 flips has the same probability. From this observation, the problem naturally becomes a combinatorics problem because we are counting outcomes in the manner you outlined in your question.

Comment: (+1) but I still don't understand. Why are you allowed to use combinations in probability?

Comment: Well, would you rather prohibit the use of combinatorics in probability theroy?